# my navbar goes up instead of down

Tags: jquery, css, nav, navigationbar

I want to make a dropdown navbar on scroll using jquery. I had the margin on negative value before to make it stick to the top but then it slides up instead of down and when the value isnt negative, my navbar dsnt stick to the top, how can I get this to work?

```js
// hide .navbar first
$("#header").hide();

// fade in .navbar
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {

             // set distance user needs to scroll before we start fadeIn
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $("#header").slideToggle("slow");
        } else {
            $("#header").fadeOut();
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#header {
   position:fixed;
   z-index:4;
   margin-top: -55px;
   padding-top:50px;
   width: 100% 
}
```

```html
<div id="header">here i have a <nav> and some buttons</div>
```

Should I use "nav" on toggle in jquery or #header or does it matter?

Comment: Add fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: `$('#header').FadeOut()` is not a function, it should be `fadeOut()` with the lowercase `f` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains a few problems:

- `$("#header").slideToggle("slow");` runs every time you scroll. This means that if your header is hidden it will appear, but if it is visible it will be hidden.
- Your HTML contains a few problems. `<nav>` for example. This tag is never closed?
- To improve loading times, it's better to hide header in your css instead of your JQuery file.

Here's a (new) working example:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $("#header").slideDown("slow");
  } else {
    $("#header").slideUp('slow');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
  margin: 0px;
}
#header {
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">Header</div>
```

Comment: i used your code but it only worked for me while i was changing my margin-top, otherwise it will appeare instantly instead of sliding. any clue?

Answer (score 0):

in your code the problem with **`slideToggle();`** while you scroll over 100 the header toggle slide up and down with each scroll .. so you should use `slideDown();`   and use `fadeOut()` instead of `FadeOut()`  .. and I think its better to use `slideUp();`

```
// fade in .navbar
$(function () {
    // hide .navbar first
    $("#header").hide();
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        // set distance user needs to scroll before we start fadeIn
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $("#header").slideDown("slow"); //you can use fadeIn();
        } else {
            $("#header").slideUp('slow'); // you can use fadeOut();
        }
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/sq3z6n4b/)

Answer (score -1):

im sure these tips did work but for some reason it didnt work in my code so maybe there is something wrong in my css?

```
[my css.html.jquery]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e19dvqpm/